# Using Schema.org's "keywords" property - and keyword stuffing

Tags: seo, google-search, keywords, schema.org, keyword-stuffing

I'm including rich snippets on a website, and I'd like to use the Schema.org property for a list of keywords:

https://schema.org/keywords

> Keywords or tags used to describe this content. Multiple entries in a keywords list are typically delimited by commas.

These words are typically comma delimited and included on the page.

How does this not fly in the face of Google's own definition of keyword stuffing?

> Keyword stuffing" refers to the practice of loading a webpage with keywords or numbers in an attempt to manipulate a site's ranking in Google search results. Often these keywords appear in a list or group, or out of context (not as natural prose).

It seems like Schema.org's suggestion to include a keyword list could actually have negative SEO value instead of the obviously intended positive value.

Anyone have any experience with how to best include a list of keywords tags?

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between adding Keyword Tags (like in WordPress tags) & Keyword Stuffing.

Keyword Stuffing is a horrible practice. [See this example](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/avoid-keyword-stuffing/). Pretty bad, eh?

Keyword Tags: However, could have their own archive page to filter content, where categories (in a website's structure) cannot be defined.

These are also used on Knowledge-base articles where it shows: `*Applies To: A, B, C*`

When that becomes, `Applies To: A+A, A+B, A+C, B+C, C+A,` & so on, it becomes stuffing.

Comment: Oooh.. yeah that's bad.  Okay... yeah I was sitting here worrying about 4 contextually relevant tags, and there are people pasting in lists of hundreds of unrelated words. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You're most welcome. Best wishes :)